# Exporting large audio files

Tags: ios

I created an audio recorder app that saves audio files in m4a format.  I then decided to add an export feature to allow users to email and text their audio recordings.  This works nicely when the audio files are no bigger than 20MB.  However, any audio file above 20MB will fail to export.  What would be the best way to export files out of the app?  I was thinking google drive or dropbox, but the user would have to have a registered account.  Are there any services that I can upload a file to and receive a link that can be emailed to the user?

Comment: CloudKit might be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of services like that. [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) is an example. Here is an overview: http://alternativeto.net/software/dropbox/

Comment: Great link! Is there a service like the one I described (no user registration required) that is the most well known/popular

Comment: I always thought Dropbox to be the most well known. Note that the user registration in Dropbox is just for you, not for your users, as far as i know. So you could build that into your app.

Comment: Kind of confused.  If I go down the dropbox path, when the user wants to export a file, they'd have to be registered with dropbox in order to upload the file, right?

Comment: Somebody needs to be registered to upload the file. That could be you with a username/password baked into the app. Then you can share the file with everybody, and the user should be able to download without login. But I may be wrong, it is a while since I used Dropbox.